# Can we access inner function outside its scope of outer function in python using outer function?

Tags: python, function, scope

**Just for the sake of curiosity I wanna know this..**
I know scope of inner function is limited to outer function body only, but still is there any way so that we can access the inner function variable outside its scope or call the inner function outside its scope ?

```
In [7]: def main():
   ...:     def sub():
   ...:         a=5
   ...:         print a
   ...:         

In [8]: main()

In [9]: main.sub()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dubizzle/webapps/django/dubizzle/<ipython-input-9-3920726955bd> in <module>()
----> 1 main.sub()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sub'

In [10]:
```

Comment: that I can do, still its a question of curiosity only that we can do it or not...

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. Use the principle of least surprise.

Comment: I'm trying to actually do this (not 'just for the sake of curiosity') in the interest of unit testing a function nested inside another function, which is nested inside a class. I'd really appreciate hearing if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> def main():
...     def sub():
...         a=5
...         print a
... 
>>> main.__code__.co_consts
(None, <code object sub at 0x2111ad0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
>>> exec main.__code__.co_consts[1]
5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can if you return the inner function as a value

```
>>> def main():
...     def sub():
...         a = 5
...         print a
...     return sub
...
>>> inner = main()
>>> inner()
5
```

or you can attach it to main as a property (functions are objects after all):

```
>>> def main():
...     def sub():
...         a = 5
...         print a
...     main.mysub = sub
...
>>> main()
>>> main.mysub()
5
```

but you better document your very good reason for doing this, since it will almost certainly surprise anyone reading your code :-)

Comment: @jamylak he asked for _any_ way to access the inner function's scope, and returning the closure certainly is _a_ way of doing that.  I've updated my answer with another way of doing it that resembles the OP's attempted syntax more...

Comment: Pretty sure OP wanted to access the function without changing the code. Nevertheless I agree that this is still a valid answer.

Comment: This reminds me of JavaScript :) This is a fantastic pattern indeed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The inner function is not an attribute of the outer function.

The inner function only exists after its `def` statement is executed (while the outer function is executed), and it stops to exist when the function exits.

You could `return` the inner function, of course.

Answer (score 1):

A function is just another object in Python and can be introspected.

You can get the outer function body at runtime and parse/eval it to make the function available in the current namespace.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def outer():
        def inner():
            print "hello!"
>>> inspect.getsourcelines(outer)
([u'def outer():\n', u'    def inner():\n', u'        print "hello!"\n'], 1)
```

Not really the same thing as calling outer.inner(), but if you are not making the inner function explicitly available outside the scope of the outer function, I guess it is the the only possibility.

For example, a very naive eval attempt could be:

```
>>> exec('\n'.join([ line[4:] for line in inspect.getsourcelines(outer)[0][1:] ]))
>>> inner()
hello!
```

Comment: @jamylak: really? more hacky than gnibbler's solution?

Comment: Yes, there is a tonne of slicing and you have to slice each line and then join them back together which makes it very unreadable. 

btw. you can remove the square brackets in the list comprehension to make it a generator which is more efficient and avoids creation of the intermediary list.

Comment: @jamylak: IMHO this is good enough for a proof of concept (unless I'm getting paid to write one). It was labeled as naive and not as a good example of code. Your claim that a generator is always more efficient than a list comprehension is false.

Comment: I didn't say it was always more efficient but there is no need for an intermediary list in this case, so without the list comp is the right way to do it.

Comment: @jamylak: would you remove the downvote if I change the list comprehension to a generator or are you just trolling?

Comment: No I still would still think this is too hacky but I'm not trolling.

Answer (score 0):

An inner function  is just a local variable like any other so the same rules apply. If you want to access it you have to return it.